# List of Codeigniter Functions

Tags: php, list, function, codeigniter

I want the list of all functions of Codeigniter to develop a program for Codeigniter auto syntax complete. Can any one please provide me the list of all functions of Codeigniter.

Comment: i need list that contain all function like $this->load->library() etc

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/
```

Click table of contents at the top right

These are some of the functions:

```
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html
```

Comment: i need list that contain all function like $this->load->library() etc

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html - this was listed in one of the links in the table of contents

Answer (score 0):

Either comb through the source files yourself or use a documentation tool like [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/).

Even the CI user guide does not list all the available functions (for example, it does not list any private class methods or many of the functions in `core/Common.php`).

A good IDE should be able to take care of the autocomplete after scanning the CI files in your project without extra effort on your part.